# How can I style the link in the following code

Tags: css

```
<p class="butonat">
<a href="#"><span class="color1">Learn More&nbsp;</span></a>
```

I tried the following `css` but didn't work:

**CSS** (added from comment post by OP):

```
.butonat a.color1 { 
   font-size:16px; 
   font-family:'Source Sans Pro', FontAwesome, sans-serif; 
   font-weight:normal; 
   text-decoration:none; 
   text-align:center; 
   color:#fff; 
}
```

Comment: In the following code.. ?

Comment: Where is your CSS code???

Comment: What do you mean ? your question is far from obvious, you can style also without the span if needed

Comment: Thank You. But first time I opened the account in here so I dont know to use it perfectly with all codes.

Comment: the css code i used was this:
.butonat a.color1 
{
 font-size:16px;
 font-family:'Source Sans Pro', FontAwesome, sans-serif;
 font-weight:normal;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-align:center;
 color:#fff;
 
}

Comment: @KreniMrv check my answer. this will give you proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of different ways accessing your link via DOM.

Here is couple of code snippets, how you can do it.

```css
.color1 {
color: red;
}

a span.color1 { 
font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<p class="butonat">
  <a href="#"><span class="color1">Learn More&nbsp;</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
After you sent your css, i can see a missing `SPACE` in your selector:
`.buttonat a.color1` this would mean that your a-tag has the class color1
change to
`.buttonat a .color1` this will select the children witch class color1 in your a tag

Comment: Please give more of an explanation in your answer. OP deserves more than 'try this:' or 'like this:' answers.

Comment: in a comment, i cant style the code and some other people would come and critique the comment. so I can't make everyone happy. I am trying to help. And in fact, when I wrote my answer the OP didn't send his CSS in his question.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS:

```css
.butonat > a {
  color:green;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.butonat > a:hover {
  color:red;
  text-decoration:underline;
}
```

```html
<p class="butonat">
<a href="#"><span class="color1">Learn More&nbsp;</span></a>
</p>
```

Use the above way to add the CSS on anchor tag. This way is used to apply the same CSS on a block of class.

You can apply more properties on it also.

**UPDATE:**

As post the CSS in question:

You need to give the space between a and class name:

```
.butonat a .color1 {
          ^^ here need space
```

Reason: you have not given the space to it is considering that class name is in anchor tag. After giving the space it will consider that class name is in the adjacent tag. so you need to give the space.